# Loop For with Zip(), selecting the number of records to be printed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code that works normally, however it only select 4 values from `entrada`. I would like to be able to set this amount per parameter.

```
def pdd(number, entrada):
    for i, j, k, l, m in zip(entrada[:-1], entrada[1:], entrada[2:], entrada[3:], entrada[4:]):
        if number in i:
            print([j, k, l, m])

list_pad = [[1, 9], [1, 15], [1, 10], [1, 11], [1, 12], [1, 13], [1, 15], [1, 14], [1, 15], [1, 16], [1, 17], [1, 18]]

pdd(15, list_pad)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 10], [1, 11], [1, 12], [1, 13]]
[[1, 14], [1, 15], [1, 16], [1, 17]]
```

Basically it will parse the input, which in the case is a list with small lists. Then it analyzes the input, and by identifying an item (list) that has the number passed by the `number` parameter, it will print the next 4 items (lists). This code already does, but I'd like to be able to set the amount by a parameter passed to the function (instead of 4)

But instead of seleting 4 records, I would like to be able to set the quantity per parameter.

Example:

```
pdd(15, list_pad, 6)
```

And should leave:

```
[[1, 10], [1, 11], [1, 12], [1, 13], [1, 15], [1, 14]]
```

Example 2:

```
pdd(15, list_pad, 2)
```

And should leave:

```
[[1, 10], [1, 11]]
[[1, 14], [1, 15]]
[[1, 16], [1, 17]]
```

How to do this?

Comment: It might help if you explain the logic here, since you are asking for help in extending it.

Comment: @ScottHunter Basically it will parse the input, which in the case is a list with small lists. Then it analyzes the input, and by identifying an item (list) that has the number passed by the `number` parameter, it will print the next 4 items (lists). This code already does, but I'd like to be able to set the amount by a parameter passed to the function (instead of 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression that iterates and slices `entrada` over the range of `n`, the new parameter specifying the number of output records, and unpack its output as arguments to `zip`:

```
def pdd(number, entrada, n):
    for i, *j in zip(entrada, *(entrada[i:] for i in range(1, n + 1))):
        if number in i:
            print(j)
```

Comment: I had the same solution in mind, but I used a list instead of a generator, I wasn't aware that the spread operator was also working on generators.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a LOT simpler:

```
def pdd(num,data,len):
    for i,v in enumerate(data[:-len]):
        if num in v:
            print(data[i+1:i+len+1])
```